# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2

Tags: java

Getting the error in the title when trying to run the program... but it compiles as well, so I'm really confused. I tried to check the other posts about this error but I couldn't get them to fix my issue.

I think that it has to do with formatting and before I had a (String.format before printing the integers, but read in a post to not do that. What's the issue?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog3 {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    /*-----
    //      Liam Lockhart
    //      Program 3
    //      Calculates number of boxes and revenue
    //      Calculates number of loose parts and revenue from them
    //-----*/

    //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

double boxRevenue;
double loosePartsRevenue;
double totalRevenue;

    //assigning variables

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Takes user input

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of containers.");
int containers = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of rows in each container.");
int rows = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of columns in each container.");
int columns = input.nextInt();

int totalParts = containers * rows * columns;

int boxes = totalParts / 12;

int looseParts = totalParts % 12;

boxRevenue = boxes * 11.50;

loosePartsRevenue = looseParts * 4.75;

totalRevenue = (loosePartsRevenue)*(boxRevenue);

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Boxes:");

System.out.println("%.2d ", "boxes");

System.out.println("Loose Parts:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here (it does not even compile):

```
System.out.println("%.2d ", "boxes");
```

Probably you had the `String.format("%.2d", boxes)` there which indeed throws a `java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2`.

So either keep the `String.format` but change it to:

```
String formattedBoxes = String.format("%d", boxes);
System.out.println(formattedBoxes);
```

or just print the `boxes` integer

```
System.out.println(boxes);
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

package com.amex.csrt.crm.service;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*-----
    //      Liam Lockhart
    //      Program 3
    //      Calculates number of boxes and revenue
    //      Calculates number of loose parts and revenue from them
    //-----*/

    // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    double boxRevenue;
    double loosePartsRevenue;
    double totalRevenue;

    // assigning variables

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Takes user input

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of containers.");
    int containers = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of rows in each container.");
    int rows = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of columns in each container.");
    int columns = input.nextInt();

    int totalParts = containers * rows * columns;

    int boxes = totalParts / 12;

    int looseParts = totalParts % 12;

    boxRevenue = boxes * 11.50;

    loosePartsRevenue = looseParts * 4.75;

    totalRevenue = (loosePartsRevenue) * (boxRevenue);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Boxes:");

    System.out.println("%.2d "+ boxes);
}
```

}

Input:
10 12 10

Output:

Please enter the amount of containers.
Please enter the amount of rows in each container.
Please enter the amount of columns in each container.

Boxes:
%.2d 100

Comment: `%.2d` is a format specifier (although wrongly typed), it should not appear as is in the output, rather format the output. For more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Please use this: System.out.printf("%2d ", boxes); This will solve the issue... You use the correct format specifier you want. This should solve your issue